# use sqlite with node.js - working module

Tags: sqlite, node.js

I'm working on a node.js project and I would like to use some kind of database to store application data. I've searched for various DBMS and I've selected SQLite because I want my project to be able to run without installing heavy DBMS and because I want it to run both on linux and windows. however, all modules that we found, that connect node with SQLite are either very old, or cannot be installed due to bugs.

so, I want to ask if nowadays, 2012, there is a completely functional node.js module for SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

I did a project last July (2012) in Node.JS v0.8.8, using the `node-sqlite` module (see https://github.com/developmentseed/node-sqlite3) and it worked just fine.

And, I successfully deployed and used this module on Heroku. However, the deployed portion of the project only involved reading out of the SQLite database – not writing. I suspect that writing into a SQLite deployed on Heroku would cause some issues, because it involves modifying the SQLite file in the file system, which AFAIK Heroku doesn't let you do.

Comment: it is not working properly. I've installed everything and I run the example that they have on the first page (https://github.com/developmentseed/node-sqlite3#usage). but it seems that data is not stored pemanenlty. On every request, I get the same values (1-10) and if I try to open the table without first creating it, it cannot be found